# Bot send message after user click on reaction and when he delete his reaction (python, discord)

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have two channels in dc:

- Channel_a
- Channel_b

Channel_a is closed for users.
They can see this channel, but they can not write. They can only click on reactions.
[image: Screen 1]

I need a bot which when someone click to reaction :one:, bot will send message in channel_b with @nick the users who click on this reaction.

Eg. User with nick @Professore click on reation :one:. In channel_a we have

[image: Screen 2]

After this bot send message in channel_b:

[image: Screen]

And when user with nick @Professor delete his reaction in channel_a bot will send another message in channel_b.

[image: Screen]

Can anyone help me complete this?

Comment: please add more relevant code and the APIs you are using to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

@client.command(aliases=['click'])
async def game(ctx):
emoji = ':one:'

```
def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.author && str(reaction) == emoji
message = await ctx.send("Just click here:")
await message.add_reaction(emoji)

try:
    await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout = 30.0, check = check)
    await ctx.send('Hello @rs10 user')
except:
    await message.delete()  # The message will be deleted if the user doesn't react with :one: within 30 second
```

I found something like this and i tried to use it. This is hard ;/